jumping from bootloader to application HardFault error STM32F103C8
i write bootloader in 0x8000000 to flash data of new code in address 0x800D000 by this function :
void flash_jump_to_app(void)
{
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    HAL_DeInit();
    __disable_irq();
    SCB->VTOR = FIRST_TARGET_ADDRESS;
    asm("movw r0,#0xD000  \n");
    asm("ldr   sp , [r0]  \n");
    asm("ldr   r0 , [r0,#4]  \n");
    asm("bx        r0  \n");
}

and when new main_app start generate HardFault  with these data
HSFR = 0x40000000
BFSR = 0x00000082
BFAR = 0X20005000
i think its error in vector table but i don't find it
LINKER FOR BOOTLOADER :
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);   /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 30K
}

LINKER OF APPLICATION :
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM); /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200; /* required amount of heap */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 20K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x800D000,   LENGTH = 33K
}

I TRY MANY TIMES TO CHANGE LINKER BUT CAN'T

Your code looks ok. Please show the definition of FIRST_TARGET_ADDRESS (I assume you meant it to be 0xD000).  Also show both the source code for the vector table and the final contents of it (available with arm-none-eabi-objdump -D).

PS: It isn't usual to pass control from the bootloader to the application leaving interrupts still disabled.

@TomV isn't it? It is problematic to risk calling into interrupt handlers before the application had a chance to perform its initial configuration. E.g. how would serial receive interrupt write to a ring buffer, if that ring buffer structure isn't yet initialized in memory?

@TomV do you mean assembly of reset_handler?

can you dump the disassembly and/or raw data of the vector tables?

you only fault if you try to call the application?

Please ask a separate question if you want more details about why to leave the interrupt mask clear, but basically I think that if you wrote an application that ran straight after reset, then it would expect the interrupts unmasked, so one that runs after the bootloader should expect the same.

What we need to see to diagnose the problem is the contents of the vector table after linking.  The first 8 bytes of the application binary might suffice.
